# Is it possible to compare class Millisecond? Like 00:05 seconds > 00:002 second

Tags: java, compare, milliseconds

I have added values on TimeSeries and i would like to compare them,which was before and which was after.The type of values Millisecond. I tryed different ways, but no one of them works....is it possible?
My milliseconds comes to TimeSeries from this :

```
long t = System.currentTimeMillis();

long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();

long totalTime = endTime - t;

Date time = new Date(totalTime);

final Millisecond now = new Millisecond(time);

 chartAzot.filler(now, doubleValue); //selfmade method to adds values to TimeSeries and some more logic
```

I have ArrayList of values,which was putted on my TimeSeries.Also i have clicked point on chart,which get's x value as double/millisecond/Number .

```
current=(Millisecond) localSeriesTime.get(3);
Number x1 = myPointonSeries.getX(0);
```

I tryed to change values types to Date,but got error NumberFormatExeption. I was trying to convert values to String and String to `Integer.ParseInt(myStringFromMillisecond`

Comment: Hey! Please provide the relevant code for the question in your question. Including your tries.

Comment: What is class Millisecond? We need code and examples of what you want to do.

Comment: Yes i put some edits to add context,I'm sorry

Comment: Well, when you have the start and end times as `long`s, the comparisons are nothing but simple comparisons of `long`s. I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly you are struggeling with. Btw. is `Millisecond` a custom class of yours?

Comment: In total i havent long value,but if add to my long Totaltime to ArrayList instead of Millisecond now , it may helps,will thik about it

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, you mean this class: [`Millisecond`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/Millisecond.html)

As you can see, the superclass [`RegularTimePeriod`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/RegularTimePeriod.html) implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Therefore you can compare Milliseconds by using [`Comparable#compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-).

Comment: Yes!Looks like it may work for me,would try to figure it out  how to handle with it.Thanks!